# 'Area' object is not callable

Tags: python, orm, pony

I have database on Mysql and in project I use pony orm in Flask. I need to get row from database with index 1.

Here I have routes for routing in app

### routes.py

```
from app import app
from pony.orm import *
from app.models import Area


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/user/")
@db_session
def user():
    c = Area[1]
    return c
```

Here I have models for my database

### models.py

```
from pony.orm import *
import config

db = Database()


class Country(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int,auto=True)
    name = Required(str,100)
    area = Set("Area")


class Area(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str, 100)
    country = Required(Country)
```

### When I open in browser address localhost:8888/ I get next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Area' object is not callable
```

When I made error?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call class instead of instance "Area[1]"

Comment: Yep shouldn't it be `area[1]` rather than `Area[1]`?

Comment: Try this `select(a for a in Area if a.id == 1)`

Comment: now I get TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid! Here solution:

```
def user():
    c = Area[1]
    name = c.name
    return name
```